# AngularJS/Angular 2: Restructure the json after getting 'http' response

Tags: angularjs, json, angular

**Current:**

```
[{
  "name": "a1",
  "category": "C1",
  "amount": 10
},

{
  "name": "a3",
  "category": "C1",
  "amount": 30
},

{
  "name": "a2",
  "category": "C1",
  "amount": 20
},

{
  "name": "a1",
  "category": "C2",
  "amount": 100
},

{
  "name": "a6",
  "category": "C2",
  "amount": 600
},

{
  "name": "a2",
  "category": "C2",
  "amount": 200
},

{
  "name": "a5",
  "category": "C2",
  "amount": 500
},

{
  "name": "a1",
  "category": "C3",
  "amount": 1000
},

{
  "name": "a3",
  "category": "C3",
  "amount": 3000
},

{
  "name": "a5",
  "category": "C3",
  "amount": 5000
}

]
```

**convert to:**

```
[

  {
    "name": "a1",
    "C1": 10,
    "C2": 100,
    "C3": 1000
  },

  {
    "name": "a2",
    "C1": 20,
    "C2": 200,
    "C3": -
  },

  {
    "name": "a3",
    "C1": 30,
    "C2": -,
    "C3": 3000
  },

  {
    "name": "a5",
    "C1": -,
    "C2": 500,
    "C3": 5000
  },

  {
    "name": "a6",
    "C1": -,
    "C2": 600,
    "C3": -
  }

]
```

Comment: It's no possible understand what you want [Read here how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: how to restructure a json as shown above in js/typescript ?

Comment: Doc's are you frien https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want only the properties that have been passed in (e.g. if there is no C2 for a1, then the mapped a1 will not have a C2 property):

```
var response = {} //set this equal to your original response, rather than an empty object
var list = {}
var mappedResponse = [];

let mapResponse = () => {
    response.forEach(item => {
        current = list[item.name] || {};
        current.name = item.name;
        current[item.category] = item.amount;
        list[item.name] = current;
    });

    Object.keys(list).forEach(key => {
        mappedResponse.push(list[key]);
    });

    return mappedResponse;
}
mapResponse();
```

If you wanted to explicitly declare something like null for those empty fields, rather than having them be undefined, you could change the `forEach` to look like this:

```
response.forEach(item => {
    current = list[item.name] || {};
    current.name = item.name;
    current['C1'] = item.category === 'C1' ? item.amount : current['C1'] || null;
    current['C2'] = item.category === 'C2' ? item.amount : current['C2'] || null;
    current['C3'] = item.category === 'C3' ? item.amount : current['C3'] || null;
    list[item.name] = current;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version!

Please not the output JSON you wanted contains the below line.

```
"C3": -
```

I checked whether the JSON is valid or not on [JSONLint.com](https://jsonlint.com/) and I got the below error.

> Error: Parse error on line 14: ...    "C2": 200,      "C3": - },  {       "name": 
>   ----------------------^ Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'

This will make the JSON invalid. So what is suggest is to leave out this property! Please let me know if that is fine?

```js
//starting JSON
var json = [{
  "name": "a1",
  "category": "C1",
  "amount": 10
},

{
  "name": "a3",
  "category": "C1",
  "amount": 30
},

{
  "name": "a2",
  "category": "C1",
  "amount": 20
},

{
  "name": "a1",
  "category": "C2",
  "amount": 100
},

{
  "name": "a6",
  "category": "C2",
  "amount": 600
},

{
  "name": "a2",
  "category": "C2",
  "amount": 200
},

{
  "name": "a5",
  "category": "C2",
  "amount": 500
},

{
  "name": "a1",
  "category": "C3",
  "amount": 1000
},

{
  "name": "a3",
  "category": "C3",
  "amount": 3000
},

{
  "name": "a5",
  "category": "C3",
  "amount": 5000
}

]
var out=[];
var final = [];
//code used to filter out the unique names ["a1", "a2", etc]
for (let a of json){
  if(out.indexOf(a.name) === -1){
   out.push(a.name);
  }
}
//loop through the unique names!
for (let a of out){
  var obj = {};
  //filter the object for a particular name
  for(let j of json.filter(function(x){return x.name===a})){
    //merge the objects `category` and `amount` as a object
    Object.assign(obj, {[j.category]: j.amount});
  }
  //finally push it to the final list that is `final`
  var temp = {name: a};
  Object.assign(temp, obj);
  final.push(temp);
}
//console.log the output
console.log(final);
```